# Uninstalled Xubuntu desktop - now no login screen?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, login

I installed *Xubuntu desktop environment* but didn't like it. I found a thread which listed a large command to uninstall everything. Now when my machine boots, I get a black screen and no possibility of logging in.

How do I fix this? I don't particularly want to have to reinstall Ubuntu.

The command I entered to uninstall it was this:

```
sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview alacarte bison blueman brltty-x11 catfish espeak exo-utils flex fonts-droid fonts-lyx gigolo gmusicbrowser gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs gthumb gthumb-data gtk2-engines-pixbuf indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-sound-gtk2 leafpad libabiword-3.0 libbison-dev libdigest-crc-perl libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfl-dev libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgstreamer-perl libgtk2-notify-perl libgtk2-trayicon-perl libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkspell0 libido-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libintl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libnet-dbus-perl liboobs-1-5 libotr2 libots0 librarian0 libsexy2 libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtumbler-1-0 libunique-1.0-0 libvte-common libvte9 libwv-1.2-4 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util6 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en m4 orage parole pastebinit pavucontrol pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog pidgin-otr plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text python-configobj rarian-compat ristretto screensaver-default-images scrollkeeper shimmer-themes system-tools-backends tcl8.5 thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common xbrlapi xchat xchat-common xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Press `ctrl + alt + F1`, then type in your usual username and password. Then run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: did you just install xubuntu and didn't like it? if you have no data to lose then do a fresh installation of the dustro you like

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. I installed the xubuntu desktop environment. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 2):

1. After getting blank screen type: `ctrl` +`alt` +`f1`.
2. Now edit your `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file using by
   typing: `sudo vi /etc/X11/default-display-manager`.
   It will open file in vi editor.
3. Replace everything (if it contains something) with
   `/usr/sbin/lightdm`
4. Press escape button and type `:wq!` to save change and exit.
5. Now restart your computer.

It should solve your problem.

Comment: The file is completely empty apart from the first line which says:

/usr/sbin/lightdm

What else could the problem be?

Comment: try `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: I'm afraid that also fails :(
Same error: Job failed to start

Comment: press `ctrl+alt+f1` and log in. After login type `startx` and see what happens.

Comment: That definitely works. I get the unity desktop, but with no icons in the top right and no fancy effects

Comment: Not sure but type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` ,select `lightdm` and reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't work. Is there a way of just reinstalling everything perhaps?

Comment: I think installing `gdm` will help you rightnow.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you had installed "Xubuntu-desktop" on Ubuntu? In which case "sudo apt-get install lightdm" will re-install the Ubuntu default desktop manager. You should be able to login from the black screen, try pressing "enter" to see if it makes the text appear. If you still don't see anything then press "control + alt + F2", and then press "enter".

Lightdm = Ubuntu Desktop Manager (sudo apt-get install lightdm)

xfdesktop = Xubuntu Desktop Manager (sudo apt-get install xfdesktop4)

Gdm = Gnome Desktop Manager (sudo apt-get install gdm)

KDM = KDE Desktop Manager (sudo apt-get install kdm)

Comment: Thank you for the response but this doesn't seem to have fixed it. I'm still getting a black screen and I even tried reinstalling lightdm and ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: were you able to login from the blackscreen?

Comment: Mango, seriously, did you read the op? Is this just some setup from you spammers? Such a weird conversation.

Comment: I successfully logged in by doing control + alt + F2 and logging in through the command line.

Comment: I don't know what an "OP" is, but I gave instructions for logging in and I'm not sure if that portion worked. I'm trying to figure exactly which part of my instructions aren't working.

Comment: Is this an Ubuntu or Xubuntu installation?

Comment: Ubuntu Installation.

I can get to my desktop if I type startx in the command line. Still no login screen unfortunately. The desktop has my unity sidebar but no buttons at the top right. Seems to be the 2d version as no visual effects

Comment: "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm" this will make you choose a default desktop manager. I'm just thinking perhaps you have 2 installed.

Comment: OP = original post(er). It's so common on the internet I don't know if you joking. OP, press `ctrl + alt + F1` (or F2, F3... up to F7), then type in your usual username and password. Then run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop`. Then reboot via `sudo reboot now`.

Comment: @henry No I wasn't joking.

Comment: Mango, please do familiarize yourself with the "rules" here: http://askubuntu.com/tour :) Next time, please do not post such kind of advice as an answer. It's encouraged to post it as a comment instead.

Comment: How is this advice? There are 2 reasons for logging in in text mode. the first is you don't have a DM which my answer solves. The second is you configured grub to load the os in text only mode which the OP didn't mention doing.

Comment: Okay mango, I entered that command and unfortunately I still do not get anything at start up. I'm worried maybe my graphics driver has been removed (somehow!) which is why I'm not getting any 3d effects.

Comment: If it's driver related then It's beyond my expertise. Once you've logged in in text mode you said that you are able to startx? instead try loging in and using "sudo start lightdm" this should force open the login screen.

Comment: When I type that in, I get the error:
start: Job failed to start

Comment: "sudo nano /etc/default/grub", one of the lines should read: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" . Verify it says this. Press "control + x" to exit after.

Comment: Still here if you need.